# Rim tension for MADDUX R3.0

Tags: rims, tension

Anyone know what the rim tension for MADDUX R3.0, 6061H-T6 alloy, 700c wheelset, clincher, ETRTO 622 x 14c rims? Or where I can find it. It's not listed on the Maddux web site.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find a recommended tension published anywhere for a specific wheel.

Comment: I think most rims are made for 1200N of spoke tension.